# jQuery with JS6 and single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My boss order to convert a website to single page application.

The Migrations from jQuery to React/Vuejs required a lot of refactoring in both frontends and backends. so we decided to make single page application using jQuery.

**I have do the following:**

1- I divided the document like this

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">

</div>
 <div id = "sidebar">

 </div>
 <div >
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mainTabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active "><a href="#home" class="backgroundRed">Inbox </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="root">
        
    </div>

 </div>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

You can look for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/pb6EM/1/) example to get more info about tabs design.

2- I converted all project files to js6 module.

3- I created js file for router and  to return the current container.

```
function getCurrentContainer(){
   var path = document.location.pathname.replace('/','_');
   return $('#'+path)
}
```

4- When the user click the link, I use ajax to bring the content only, then I append it to new tab.

```
$(document).on('click','a[data="no-reload"]',function(){
var path = $(this).attr('href');
if (!$('#'+path.replace('/','_')).length){
 $.ajax(..) // bring content from server and make new tab 
 }
//function to show  content of other tab and hide content of current tab
// change the document title, url and update history
});
```

5- I replaced all `$(document)` selectors by `$(currentContainer)`.

```
import {getCurrentContainer} from './my_router.js'
const $container = getCurrentContainer();
$($container). ... // instead of $(document).  ...
```

**The problem is:**

when I select input, `$('[input[name=id]')`, it will select all ids inputs of hidden tabs.
I can solve it by `$(currentContainer).find('[input[name=id]')` but it take long time to refactor all operations.

Can I reinitialize the $, to change the root to currentContainer instead of document,

`$ = ? //make currentContainer selector as root`

Comment: Can you post the exact code that is going wrong? (a minimal, reproducible example). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: if you going to use react, you might as well remove the need for jquery completely, react can do everything jquery can and it's perfect for if you want to break your pages into component parts, rather than waste time trying to make jquery work maybe focus on replacing parts of the page with react components that don't reply on jquery as that's kind of the point of react, the time and effort might be better spent especially if our only going to get ride of jquery in the long run, focus on making components, swapping them in for the old jquery parts IMHO

Comment: this might help this might help https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-jquery-inside-a-react-component

you could also try

 const $ = getCurrentContainer(); 

that might work